# one hard drive not showing in boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 20.04

My laptop has two separate hard drives, one SSD and one HDD.
i've installed ubuntu on SSD and, windows already have been installed in HDD(i reinstalled ubuntu in SSD for latest version). Now my laptop booting with ubuntu. It is not showing HDD even pressing F12 or in boot menu. How can i fix this problem?

any update?